# Adding new line/line break while writing swirl lesson "lesson.yaml" with Class "text" in RStudio

Tags: yaml, rstudio, newline, line-breaks, swirl

I am writing a swirl lesson using `swirlify` package functions in RStudio.
Below is how `lesson.yaml` file looks like now

```
- Class: text
  Output: Welcome to Part 1 Playing with Numbers!!!
```

Output for which looks like

[image]

How to insert a new line or line break after **Welcome to Part 1** in `lesson.yaml` file above, so that it displays the output as below when I run the `demo_lesson()` command again after saving the `lesson.yaml` file

**| Welcome to Part 1**

**| Playing with Numbers!!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using YAML, you can use any of these equivalent approaches:

- Quoted string with escape

```
- Class: text
  Output: "Welcome to Part 1\nPlaying with Numbers!!!"
```

- Literal scalar

```
- Class: text
  Output: |-
    Welcome to Part 1
    Playing with Numbers!!!
```

(`|` starts a literal scalar and `-` tells YAML to drop the final line break.)

- Multiline scalar

```
- Class: text
  Output:
    Welcome to Part 1

    Playing with Numbers!!!
```

(since one line break gets folded into a space, you need two line breaks.)

Since I do not know whether swirlify nicely handles line breaks in the string, I guess you could also do

```
- Class: text
  Output: Welcome to Part 1
- Class: text
  Output: Playing with Numbers!!!
```

Comment: I am working on Windows 10, and I tried `|-, |+, >, >+` everything on RStudio, its not working for me.
I know the last solution to put it in two different class sections, but I have all the contents in kind of heading and then a paragraph, so heading should be separated somehow from paragraph in the output.

Comment: How is it not working? What's happening when you do it?

Comment: I'll post my output.

Comment: Its working when I hit enter twice in the `lesson.yaml`, Thanks could you please edit your second block of code in your answer, just one more enter. Then its working with the literal `|-` 
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Same way it works with double `\n\n` for quoted string with escape, 1st block of answer

Comment: For block three without literal `|-`, it works with three times Enter and the 4th Block is already working because of two different class Sections!!!

Comment: Hey Accepted your answer, do let me know because all your answers are working with either one extra new line or extra enter.. dont know why but its working..

Comment: It seems like something is line-folding your input twice. This is either a bug in the YAML implementation or something else in the `swirlify` toolchain. I don't know any of it, so I cannot point my finger to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **flyx** for answering the question, here is how it works!!

**I. Quotes string with escape** (Works with two `\n\n`)

`lesson.yaml` file

[image]

**II. Literals**

First line in `Output:` `|-` Hit ENter once
Indent once by pressing one Tab for first line, Hit Enter twice to have break between header line and paragraph like below, then it works..

`lesson.yaml` file

[image]

**III. Mulitline Scalar** (Works with three times Enter between two lines)

Press Enter once After `Output:` in lesson.yaml
`Indent once by pressing`Tab` key once, Write your first line, hit Enter thrice and write the second line. Then it works.

`lesson.yaml` file

[image]

**OUTPUT FOR ALL THE ABOVE ANSWERS**

[image]